# Find one value and replace value inside quotes within the same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, openoffice, google-spreadsheets, frontpage

I translated values for a JS calculator but the script that I am using treats the option value the same as a value inside a parenthesis.

Currently have it on notepad ++ but can migrate to anything else to save time.

There are 4,850 lines and that would take me a day easily.

[image]

Comment: please post your sample case also in editable format, that'd make it much easier to test suggested solutions before posting.

Comment: As written, the question is not clear : Please show us what you want by including in your post the text as before and as after the transformation you want done.